# Xcode: Error importing localizations - XLIFF original attribute missing

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, xliff

I'm having an issue when importing translated strings from XLIFF back to Xcode (*Editor > Import Localizations ...*)

Xcode is giving me the following error message with no detailed description so It's difficult figuring out what is wrong.

[image]

I'm using [Lokalise.co](https://lokalise.co) to translate texts and then export them to XLIFF (the texts were imported from XLIFF too).

It's possible that some keys were removed in localise so the XLIFF has fewer keys than the file exported from Xcode. However, I have no idea what keys it might be.

Any ideas how to proceed on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message when importing a XLIFF into XCode.

You need to ensure in the `file` tag , the `original` attribute is not empty. It needs to point to the path of the string file.

[image]